# How to create a new file?

Tags: gedit

I've tried

```
gksudo gedit /etc/xinetd.d/tftp
```

(This is the file I have to create)

I got an error message

> couldn't find the file /etc/xinetd.d/tftp please check that you typed the location correctly and try again

What do I need to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In larger context: what you want to do?

In answer to question: most probably you are missing directory `/etc/xinetd.d`. Try installing `xinetd` first (`sudo apt-get install xinetd`).

Answer (score 0):

Check whether you have tftp installed, run in a terminal:

```
tftp
```

If it is not installed, install it:

```
sudo apt-get install tftp
```

Then, you can edit /etc/xinetd.d/tftp

Comment: Wrong package, tftp contents: http://packages.ubuntu.com/maverick/amd64/tftp/filelist

Answer (score 0):

I think this file is missing or directory.Have you installed this package and checked whether this file is present?

If not, just create a file at this location and then try editing it.

```
sudo touch /etc/xinetd.d/tftp
gksu gedit  /etc/xinetd.d/tftp
```

Comment: `gedit` (as well as ~every other editor in linux) automatically creates files. You don't have to `touch` it first. However, neither `gedit` or `touch` will create folders. If you want to be sure, you have to run `mkdir /etc/xinetd.d -p && touch /etc/xinetd.d/tftp` to create it. (`-p` creates recursively and do not throw error if folder already exists).